# One Collection listening to multiple models' changes in BackBone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two models `m1` and `m2` with same attributes `attr` that changes. I want to assign these two models to one collection `c1`. **`Then I want to listen to changes in 'attr' inside the collection and determine in which model 'attr' is changed.`** I tried attaching an event-listener in collection as given in some tutorials,but on changing the model's attribute 'attr',it is not listening to the change. What is the best possible approach to solve this problem? Is it possible to listen to changes like this in Backbone?

Comment: Can you show what you did? That would help explaining what you missed.

Comment: Are the two models `m1` and `m2` instances of same `Model`? If not adding them to one `collection` doesn't sound a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you set up your view like this:

```
var Vue = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        //attach a collection to the view
        this.collection = collection1;

        //fires when the 'attr' attribute changes in any model in the collection
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change:attr', this.itHasChanged);
    },
    itHasChanged: function(e) {
        alert('the model with id: ' + e.get('id') + ' has changed');
        console.log(e)
    }
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ss2BM/